# Your connection is not private Error wile trying to open my site without putting www in front

Tags: php, html, ssl

I am getting "Your connection is not private", "`NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`" error when I try to open my site without putting www in front.
`www.mine.website` is my website domain, this works fine when I try to open it like- "`https://mine.website`" but not open when I try without www - "`https://mine.website`" how to resolve this issue is that issue related to ssl or something else. I have no knowledge of ssl and all. Anyone please help me out

Comment: Open your site on another device. Probably a Dns cache

Comment: In your question, the latter two URLs appear to be identical - I presume the penultimate one  which you say works fine should include the "www." prefix?

Answer (score 1):

The SSL needs to be configured for both `www` and `non-www` versions of your domain name. It looks like its configured only for the `www` one. You can do one of the following to resolve the issue.

**Option 1**. Redirect from `non-www` to `www`. to do that you can add following to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Option 2**. Configure SSL for the `non-www` version of your domain. You can do so in the same way you configured it for the `www` version. To use Letsencrypt you can find the steps [here](https://serverspace.io/support/help/how-to-get-lets-encrypt-ssl-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thank you soo much for the answer, but where can I found this .htaccess file, I looked into my project its not there, is that file will be accessible from hosting platform's dashboard !

Comment: It must be in the same folder as our index file. The .htaccess file is enerally hidden so make sure you are viewing the hidden files as well. if there is no .htaccess you can create one. Which server and hosting panels are you using?

Comment: there is one more issue it is redirecting to http but I want it to be in https ...

Comment: Change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks for helping me but the issue is not completely resolved my site is hosted on heroku .. I tried that code but still it is not working with https:mine.website , although it is working fine with ( http ) like http:mine.website